# Can a full rank matrix minus $(1, \dots, 1)^\top(g_1(x_0), \dots, g_q(x_0))$ have also full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be a $n*n$ matrix with full rank, and $g_1, \dots, g_n$ are continuous non-constant real functions with support on some open interval. Does there exist $x_0$ such that a matrix
$$Q:= M-(1, \dots, 1)^\top(g_1(x_0), \dots, g_n(x_0))$$ has also full rank? Here, matrix $(1, \dots, 1)^\top(g_1(x_0), \dots, g_n(x_0))$ corresponds to n times repeating $g_1(x_0)$ in the first row, ... , $g_n(x_0)$ in the last row. I.e. a matrix $n*n$ with rank not larger than 1.

In fact, $g_i$ are somehow nice, and we can assume something more about them if that helps. It seems like this should hold for "typical" $x_0$ but I am struggling with finding at least one (I am interested only in existence of $x_0$). Some ideas?

Comment: The set of invertible $n\times n$-matrices is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n\cdot n}$, if you use for example the the column sum norm to define your topology, if you can now minimize the $|g_1+\dots+g_n|$ you would probably get somewhere.

Comment: It is helpful to note that $Q$ will be invertible if and only if 
$$
(g_1(x_0),\dots,g_n(x_0))M^{-1}(1,\dots,1)^\top \neq 1
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is helpful to note that $Q$ will fail to be full rank (i.e. invertible) if and only if
$$
(g_1(x_0),\dots,g_n(x_0))M^{-1}(1,\dots,1)^\top = 1.
$$
With that, we see that a satisfactory $x_0$ fails to exists if (and only if) $(g_1(x),\dots,g_n(x))$ lies within the plane $\{x : xM^{-1}(1,\dots,1)^\top = 1\}$. For instance, take any function $g_1(x)$, $g_2(x) = 1 - g_1(x)$, and
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$
For this example, there exists no $x_0$ such that $Q$ has full rank.

---

**Note:** If the functions $g_1,\dots,g_n$ are polynomials *and* there exists at least one $x_0$ for which $Q$ is not full rank, then it must hold that $Q$ will be full rank for all but finitely many values of $x_0$.

If $g_1,\dots,g_n$ are [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) and there exists at least one $x_0$ for which $Q$ is not full rank, then it must hold that $Q$ will be full rank for all but countably many values of $x_0$.